# How do wrapped types work in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, deserialization

I'm not a Java expert, but I know the basics of Java and I always try to understand Java code in depth always whenever it come across. 
It could be a really silly doubt but would love to make it clear understanding in my mind.
I'm posting in the Java community, because my doubt is about Java only.

Since the last couple of months I am working with hadoop and came across that hadoop uses its own types, which are wrapped around Java's primitive types in order to increase efficiency to send data across network on the basis of serialization and deserialization.

My confusion starts from here, Lets say we have some data in HDFS to be processed using following Java code running in hadoop code

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
public class WordCountMapper
{
extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
}
}
String line = value.toString();
for (String word : line.split(" ")){
if(word.length()>0){
context.write(new Text(word),new IntWritable(1));
}
```

In this code hadoop's types are like this LongWritable, Text, IntWritable.
Lets pick up Text type which is wrapped around String type of Java (correct me if am wrong).
My doubt here is when we are passing these parameters to our method map in the above code, how these parameters gets interact with the code which is in `import package i.e org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;`

Below is the Text class code

```
package org.apache.hadoop.io;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.Stringable;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience.Public;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability.Stable;



@Stringable
@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Stable
public class Text
  extends BinaryComparable
  implements WritableComparable<BinaryComparable>
{
  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Text.class);

  private static ThreadLocal<CharsetEncoder> ENCODER_FACTORY = new ThreadLocal()
  {
    protected CharsetEncoder initialValue() {
      return Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT).onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    }
  };



  private static ThreadLocal<CharsetDecoder> DECODER_FACTORY = new ThreadLocal()
  {
    protected CharsetDecoder initialValue() {
      return Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT).onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    }
  };



  private static final byte[] EMPTY_BYTES = new byte[0];
  private byte[] bytes;
  private int length;

  public Text()
  {
    bytes = EMPTY_BYTES;
  }


  public Text(String string)
  {
    set(string);
  }

  public Text(Text utf8)
  {
    set(utf8);
  }


  public Text(byte[] utf8)
  {
    set(utf8);
  }




  public byte[] getBytes()
  {
    return bytes;
  }

  public int getLength()
  {
    return length;
  }








  public int charAt(int position)
  {
    if (position > length) return -1;
    if (position < 0) { return -1;
    }
    ByteBuffer bb = (ByteBuffer)ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).position(position);
    return bytesToCodePoint(bb.slice());
  }

  public int find(String what) {
    return find(what, 0);
  }


  public int find(String what, int start)
  {
    try
    {
      ByteBuffer src = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, length);
      ByteBuffer tgt = encode(what);
      byte b = tgt.get();
      src.position(start);

      while (src.hasRemaining()) {
        if (b == src.get()) {
          src.mark();
          tgt.mark();
          boolean found = true;
          int pos = src.position() - 1;
          while (tgt.hasRemaining()) {
            if (!src.hasRemaining()) {
              tgt.reset();
              src.reset();
              found = false;

            }
            else if (tgt.get() != src.get()) {
              tgt.reset();
              src.reset();
              found = false;
            }
          }

          if (found) return pos;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
    catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); }
    return -1;
  }

  public void set(String string)
  {
    try
    {
      ByteBuffer bb = encode(string, true);
      bytes = bb.array();
      length = bb.limit();
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Should not have happened " + e.toString());
    }
  }


  public void set(byte[] utf8)
  {
    set(utf8, 0, utf8.length);
  }

  public void set(Text other)
  {
    set(other.getBytes(), 0, other.getLength());
  }






  public void set(byte[] utf8, int start, int len)
  {
    setCapacity(len, false);
    System.arraycopy(utf8, start, bytes, 0, len);
    length = len;
  }






  public void append(byte[] utf8, int start, int len)
  {
    setCapacity(length + len, true);
    System.arraycopy(utf8, start, bytes, length, len);
    length += len;
  }



  public void clear()
  {
    length = 0;
  }










  private void setCapacity(int len, boolean keepData)
  {
    if ((bytes == null) || (bytes.length < len)) {
      if ((bytes != null) && (keepData)) {
        bytes = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, Math.max(len, length << 1));
      } else {
        bytes = new byte[len];
      }
    }
  }



  public String toString()
  {
    try
    {
      return decode(bytes, 0, length);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Should not have happened " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  public void readFields(DataInput in)
    throws IOException
  {
    int newLength = WritableUtils.readVInt(in);
    setCapacity(newLength, false);
    in.readFully(bytes, 0, newLength);
    length = newLength;
  }

  public static void skip(DataInput in) throws IOException
  {
    int length = WritableUtils.readVInt(in);
    WritableUtils.skipFully(in, length);
  }




  public void write(DataOutput out)
    throws IOException
  {
    WritableUtils.writeVInt(out, length);
    out.write(bytes, 0, length);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if ((o instanceof Text))
      return super.equals(o);
    return false;
  }
```

May I know please when ever we run the above hadoop's code, data in HDFS flows across the parameters we have mentioned in the map method.
Once the first data set from HDFS hits the Text parameter how it flows inside the org.apache.hadoop.io.Text class?
I mean from where does it start (I'm assuming it's starting from set method in class because it has kind of same parameters as mentioned map method, am I correct?)
Where does it change from normal string type to Text type in code?

My Second doubt is: when data is stored in Text type, then who kicks it to start doing serilzation? I mean who calls this write(DataOutput out), and who calls readFields(DataInput in) once data is reached to its destination on network?
How does it work, and where do I need to look?

I hope what I am asking is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Like all network or disk operations, everything is transferred as bytes. The Text class deserializes bytes to UTF-8. The Writables determine how data is represented and Comparables determine how data is ordered.

The InputFormat set in the Job determines what Writables are given to a map or reduce Task.

An InputSplit determines how to split and read a raw byte stream into the Writables

One map task is started on each InputSplit

Refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html